# Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 known issues list?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Did anyone manage to find the list of known issues for Visual Studio 2010 beta 2? Readme in the installation folder redirects me to the beta 1 list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can imagine that since the general public release of Beta2 is Wednesday, and since the Beta1 doc was available on the MS download center, that perhaps the Beta2 readme will not be available until Wednesday.  But I am just guessing; will update if I find more info.

EDIT

Aha!

http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/3/B5379D88-51D7-4240-9423-CE1427502784/VS2010Beta2Readme.htm

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, I've just posted a small unofficial list of Beta 2 known issues from the C# IDE team. This is by no means a full list, but still better than nothing until the official list is available:
http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-known-issues.aspx

Comment: Posted Part 2 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/11/12/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-known-issues-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Custom workflow Activities don't show up in the toolbox when in Debug mode on my box.  If I switch to release and rebuild they appear.

---

Other bugs I've submitted:

[Context menu position incorrect/extends off screen](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=503893)
[Strongly-typed dataset designer doesn't globally qualify namespaces](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=508231)
[SortedList adds an empty entry (key and value both null) in certain situations](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509302)
[Xaml editor isn't picking up assembly xmlns definitions nor is giving the option for mapping namespaces to assemblies](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509545)
[Workflows can only extend Activity, precluding the use of custom base workflow classes](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509549)
[Workflow designer ignores partial class members](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509593)
[Tool windows forget what monitor they are on](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509790)
[Custom workflow actions don't show in the toolbox in Debug mode](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509804)

Comment: If you'd like us to investigate this bug, please log it at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback. Thanks!